# Считать одну строку в подгруженом файле

Tags: latex

Пытаюсь считать только одну строку из файла.

win1.txt (наполнение файла ):

```
Фролов 
Cельдеренко
```

Единственное как могу прочитать — только полностью:

```
\input{win1.txt}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, способен ли Latex считывать из файла (раздельно) построчно.

Answer (score 1):

у оператора `\input` нет такой возможности.

вы можете воспользоваться более низкоуровневыми средствами, как описано в ответах на этот, например, вопрос: [\input only part of a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4889/79376)

но, возможно, вам подойдёт и [оператор `\lstinputlisting` из пакета *listings*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34323/79376), с помощью которого можно указать диапазоны выводимых строк:

```
...
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-2}]{win1.txt}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=2]{win1.txt}
...
```

---

- чуть больше информации: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings
- полная документация по пакету *listings*: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf (по поводу диапазонов — раздел «4.4 the printed range»).

Comment: Спасибо но я работаю в latex2rtf-2.3.1_win-NO-GUI там такую команду не понимает latex

Comment: @timob256, так задайте [вопрос разработчику](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/support.html).

Comment: @timob256, или воспользуйтесь [fork-ом](https://github.com/magsilva/latex2rtf), в котором [команда `lstlisting` реализована](https://github.com/magsilva/latex2rtf/commit/11a65a5bea190b58d46ad2e421bed6c3984401c6). // и, на будущее: подобные **существенные** ограничения лучше указывать сразу в вопросе, а не в комментариях.